# How to make site logo "Change to a new logo" with screen size

Tags: html, css

Currently I call my logo to my site in HTML code with:

```
<img alt="" src="images/Logo.png">
```

I have tried using @media in CSS, and a few of my own in-text HTML ideas and I cannot figure out how to make the logo change to a new logo regarding to screen resolution.

I AM NOT trying to make the logo "Change Size", I am trying to literally make the logo change to a new logo with screen size

Comment: Well you can simply create a `div` and change its background according to `@media`.

Comment: media queries should work. show us what you have tried? It might help us to figure out where you have gone wrong.

Comment: My ideas have drug out to an extent in which I wouldn't even prefer to use. I am open and capable of any new ideas to implement. Thank you guys :)

Comment: So media queries along with logo as a background image might be first thing for you to explore. I assume you couldn't achieve anything with media queries so far, as they do not change image which is included in markup. Good luck!

Comment: You're correct. So setting the image as a background within the media querie should do it!

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#adaptive-images

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want simply by using the background of an element :

```
<div id="logo"></div>

#logo
{
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    width: Xpx;
    height: Xpx;
}

@media(...)
{
    #logo
    {
        background-image: url("images/OtherLogo.png");
    }
}
```

Ortherwise you can use CSS to change the `img` `src` but this is not compatible with all browsers :

```
@media(...)
{
    img
    {
        content: url("images/OtherLogo.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try first tonight!

Comment: i am shocked that last technique works in *any* browser. i don't think it works by replacing the src attribute, however, i think it replaces the content entirely with an image. to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/g71kqgv7/

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a way to change the logo while keeping a responsive menu under it. I came up with the following: 
HTML:

```
   <div class="logo" ><a href="index.html" ><img class="logoreg"src="your/image/here.png"  style='width:100%; max-width:300px' alt="" border="0">
<img class="logo240"src="your/image/here.png"  style='width:100%; max-width:300px' alt="" border="0" />
```

CSS:

```
    .logo {

    width:100%; 

    padding: 20px 0px 15px 0px;

}

.logoreg {
    visibility:visible; 
    max-width:300px;
}

.logo240 {

    visibility:hidden;
    max-width:220px;

}
```

And for the Change over:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

.logoreg {
    visibility:hidden;  
     position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;

}

.logo240 {

    visibility:visible;
}
}
```

The outcome was that when the screen size was above 320px, the larger image would show and the smaller image would be pushed behind the menu layer, removing the gap from a hidden object.

It would reverse when the image reached 320px or less.  If anyone sees any flaws in this. Please let me know! Thanks!